# String comparsion after parsing httpresponse in android

Tags: android, string, httpresponse

Well I can not understand why string comparison not working

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) 
{
   DefaultHttpClient httpClient =   new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httpPost            =   new HttpPost(url_login);
   httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
   HttpResponse httpResponse    =   httpClient.execute(httpPost);
   HttpEntity entity            =   httpResponse.getEntity();
   InputStream is               =   entity.getContent();
   String returnState           =   new String();
   returnState                  =   convertStreamToString(is);


   Log.d("retunState ", returnState); // returning desired string

   //if (returnState=="user") // this is not working, however returnState = user
   // OR 
   //if (returnState.equals("user")) 
   // OR
   if (returnState.equalsIgnoreCase("user")) // this is not working also
   {                        
      Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, SecondPage.class);
      startActivity(i);
      finish();
   }

} // close of doInbackgorund function

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) 
{

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
StringBuilder sb      = new StringBuilder();

String line = null;
try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append((line + "\n"));
            }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
    try {
           is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
 return sb.toString();
}
```

Well the all the three if-conditions do not give any error and the second activity never start even if returnState = user or returnState= no_user. I want to start another activity if returnState = user but in any case, it just does not go in if block

Comment: Because you're not using .equals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first `if` statement is skipping your next statement as it is false. Comment out the first if.

Its possible you also have whitespace in your returnState. Try using `.trim()`

```
//if (returnState=="user") 
if (returnState.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("user")) 
{                        
   Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, SecondPage.class);
   startActivity(i);
   finish();
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it by about 10 seconds.

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan So your saying `"no_user".equals("user");` returns true? I think you need to check what your `returnState` variable actually contains. Check the log.

Comment: Yes I am checking in logcat, it shows me user but if condition never gets true.

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan Try `if (returnState.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("user"))` Maybe there is added whitespace. :)

Comment: thanks Doomsknight! I wasted 2 days in it, and it was headache for me. The trim function worked for me. I am new to android. logcat cheated me..

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan. No probs. Glad I could help. Yea white space is hard to detect, since its seemingly invisible! I had the same problem a while back.

Comment: @Doomsknight can I have your email for android programming?